# How to refactor php foreach using Laravel (Eloquent's) map collection function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, refactoring

I've just watched Adam Wathan's video on [Refactoring Loops and Conditionals](https://vimeo.com/115719437), and feel like I can use the [map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map) collection method in the `sumLeagueStats` method on my `Team` model (rather than the foreach).

I have a relationship on teams -> leagues, and the `getLeagueStats` function gets all of the stats (played, won, drew, lost, for, against, points) from the `leagues` table for the relevant team.

In the `sumLeagueStats` method I was going to use a `foreach` loop and loop through each stat by year, and take the sum of all of the played, etc, and return it, but having watched the above video,

```
class Team extends Model {

    public function league()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('league');
    }

    public function getLeagueStats($year = [2018])
    {
        return $this->league()->whereIn('year', [$year])->get();
    }

    public function sumLeagueStats($year = [2018])
    {
        foreach {
            ...
            return
        }
        /*
        * Want to return a colleciton with the following:
        *
        $this->getLeagueStats()->sum('played');
        $this->getLeagueStats()->sum('won');
        $this->getLeagueStats()->sum('drew');
        $this->getLeagueStats()->sum('lost');
        $this->getLeagueStats()->sum('for');
        $this->getLeagueStats()->sum('against');
        $this->getLeagueStats()->sum('points');
        */
    }
}
```

I'm new to Laravel, so firstly want to check. my suspicions are correct, and secondly looking for any insight/resource for more information, as the docs are slightly lacking).

Comment: I've slightly tweaked the code to make it more understandable/readable so let me know if anything is missing/unclear.

Comment: Can you show the code you had inside the foreach loop originally?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `getLeagueStats` everytime is making a request to your database everytime you call the `sum` method, so you can create a variable to work with and create a collection that represents the data :

```
$stats = $this->getLeagueStats();
return collect([
    'played' => $stats->sum('played'),
    'won' => $stats->sum('won'),
    'drew' => $stats->sum('drew'),
    'won' => $stats->sum('won'),
    'lost' => $stats->sum('lost'),
    'for' => $stats->sum('for'),
    'points' => $stats->sum('points')
]);
```

is that a what you want ?

Comment: Sort of, but I was hoping to make it a bit more generic. I wanted to loop through the collection that is returned with `getLeagueStats` and sum all of the points on it, so if I added another field (eg goal diff), it would also return the sum of that. Hence the map.